# How to reuse `Uri` object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

For optimization purposes I want to reuse `Uri` object instead of initializing a new one multiple times.

I don't want this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("test");
uri = new Uri("test2");
uri = new Uri("test3");
```

but I want something like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("test");
uri.AbsoluteUri = "test2";
uri.AbsoluteUri = "test3";
```

Is it possible to reuse `Uri` object instead of creating new one?

Comment: This seems like a premature optimisation to me; have you identified a performance issue?

Comment: I'm unclear what savings you think you would achieve be avoiding a constructor and instead assigning a string given that the same parsing overheads would probably be incurred in either case.

Comment: The [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0) contains quite a few other properties besides `AbsoluteUri`. Only changing that property might cause problems on the long run, i.e you'll have inconsistent data. Besides that, I doubt creating a few instances will cause any performance issues. Also, the constructor does some additional processing that you're skipping.

Comment: If you want to make it easier to create lots of different `Uri` objects for similar URIs without coding repetition, you could consider using the `UriBuilder` class to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `UriBuilder`. `Uri` class is immutable and all the properties are read only. `UriBuilder` provides an alternative which allows to modify the properties of underlying `Uri` instance by providing mutable properties. However, you need to be careful while changing the values as you need to make sure each and every property corresponds to your new uri. Have a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-5.0

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.example.com")
Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri)   //prints http://www.example.com
uriBuilder.Host = "www.google.com"
Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri)   //prints http://www.google.com
```

You have to always make sure that whenever you are changing any property, other properties also remain consistent with what you want to achieve for e.g. the `UserName` and `Password` properties might also need to be changed when a `Host` is changed.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a unique sequence of characters
> that identifies a logical or physical resource used by web
> technologies. URIs may be used to identify anything, including
> real-world objects, such as people and places, concepts, or
> information resources such as web pages and books.

So as a URI is unique, then it should not be possible to change the URI string, but instead you should have a different URI for each unique string.  And hence you need to create a new object for each one and can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Uri is immutable, so the class properties are read-only.

It looks like you can use the UriBuilder if you need to modify elements of Uri after creation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0